# How to create a stacked histogram with percentages, so that the fill variable is the percentage of the x-variables percentage?

Tags: percentage, geom-bar, stacked-chart

I need to do a bar chart, or histogram, including 3 variables.
Variable "Block" shall be in the facet_grid option. 
On the x-axis shall be the variable H18SkaBet. And on the y-axis H18Skada.
The bins shall represent in total H18 SkaBet of each Block, and stacked with H18Skada.  It should be  basically a graph as the code underneath, just in percent.

```
ggplot(ThuSve, aes(H18SkaBet, fill = factor(H18Skada), colors= H18Skada)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.5)+
  facet_grid(~Block, labeller=labeller(Block = labels))+
  scale_x_continuous((name="Damage severity"))+
  scale_y_continuous(name="Number of seedlings")+
  theme_dark()+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#CCFF99","#CCCCCC","#CCFFFF","#CC9966","#33CC99", "#339900", "#FF0033", "#666666"),
                    name  ="Damage cause",
                    breaks=c("0", "1","2","3", "4", "5", "6","7","8", "9"),
                    labels=c("No Damage", "Fungus","Frost", "Drought", "Winter dessication", "Vegetation", "Game","Insects", "Pine Weevil", "Other/Unknown"),
                    aesthetics = "fill")
```

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to answer without any data.

But if you want percentage values, maybe this link can be useful :
[How to plot a 'percentage plot' with ggplot2](https://sebastiansauer.github.io/percentage_plot_ggplot2_V2/).